# Use NodeJs in Kotlin Android Project to use Stream.io Feed Api?

Tags: getstream-io

Would it be advisable to some how integrate NodeJs with a Kotlin project to use Stream.io Feed API? From what I understand there currently isn't any support for Kotlin/Android regarding the Feed capability. I currently have an iOS app that uses Stream and would like to connect my Android users to the community also. If this isn't the right way to thin about this, is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/getstream/stream-java provides java integration for feeds. See its `io.getstream.cloud` package to leverage it in android.

Later this year, more modern and android specific SDK will be developed too.